# BroadcastReceiver is not receiving broadcast intents

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I need to send broadcast intent for specific receiver.
I use this function for it:

```
void sendTestBroadcast(Class<? extends BroadcastReceiver> clazz) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, clazz);
    intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Then I handle results in my Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mReceiver = new Receiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(MY_ACTION));
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    mReceiver = null;
}
```

`Receiver` is private and non-static class. I pass `Receiver.class` to my receiver sender as an argument. I also tried to use `ComponentName` to set destanation target, but it's still not working. I even tried to do `Receiver` class static -- same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does your `onReceive()` look in your `Activity`?

Comment: @Emmanuel it is not invoked anyway. Checked in the debugger and LogCat.

Comment: Can you post that whole `Activity` please?

Comment: also post your manifest - if you've declared it there